# Formatting of heading List of Acronyms and list of tables glossaries package

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I am using glossaries package and making List of Acronyms as well as List of Symbols. I got everything working except one formatting issue.
The heading of my above two lists have a different formatting (centered and smaller font) then my List of Figure and List of tables (left justified and bigger font). I want heading of my list of acronyms and symbols to have same formatting as list of tables and figure.

Here is an example of list of table which is what I want

[image]

but my list of acronym looks like this:

[image]

My print command for acronyms is as follows:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=list,title=List of Acronyms]
```

I would appreciate if somebody can help me here. I have moderate skills in LaTeX.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\bfseries}
\chapterfont{\centering\Large} 
\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
\newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{Appendix }}
}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries} 
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries  
\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}
\newglossaryentry{Pi}{
name=$\pi$,
description={A mathematical constant whose value is the ratio of any circle's circumference to its diameter.},
sort=symbpi, type=symbolslist
}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\printglossaries
\include{Sample}
\chapter{Sample}
This is my \gls{sa} and I can use it again. This is a symbol \gls{Pi}.
\begin{table}
 \caption{Sample Table}
\end{table}
\updatechaptername
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see what class you're using.

Comment: Hi Nicola, I am using a template from my university which includes a .sty file and a preamble etc etc. I don't think I would be able to do that (provide MWE) although I want to. The template did not have the glossary function and i added myself. But I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without that stuff in a minimal document? If not, the problem arises *because* of that stuff and you need to figure out what. (Certainly nobody here can without seeing it!) If it still arises, then post the minimal code as the customised stuff is not the cause of the problem. Without code it is going to be pretty near impossible for anybody to help you. The best anybody could do is hazard a guess.

Comment: @Tash Try using [a building up approach](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/buildingup.html) or [a hacking down approach](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html) to create a minimal document. Unfortunately we can't help otherwise. `glossaries` uses `\chapter*` or `\section*` for the header by default, so something in your code (or the class you're using) is overriding this.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @Nicola As I said I am relatively new to Latex so creating a MWE which includes a preamble and style file from my university will be a bit difficult for me. However, I kind of know what is happening:

Comment: In the preamble file, there is a piece of code which is overriding the traditional chapter headings (using package 'sectsty') for report document class so chapter headings are centered and smaller and different than the List of Table and Figures (which still uses original chapter heading style). Now when i print glossary, it (as you said) uses chapter style which is now smaller and centered therefore different then the LOF and LOT heading.
Now the situation can be corrected if I can modify the heading of glossary to traditional chapter heading. How?

Comment: I can also comment the code that is making chapter headings different but i like those heading and want to keep them. 
And thanks Nicola for welcoming me :)

Comment: The code that is changing the chapter heading style is this:
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\bfseries}% set all the section font to bfseries
\chapterfont{\centering\Large} % set the sizes of chapters, sections ...
\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}

Comment: @Tash building a MWE is not _that_ complicated. If you follow the link Nicola provided you should find enough help to create one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `tocloft` package that's changing the style of `\listoftables` etc, but it doesn't use the standard `\section` or `\chapter` commands, which is why the list of acronyms isn't matching. You need to modify the definition of `\glossarysection` to make it match:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\bfseries}
\chapterfont{\centering\Large} 
\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
\newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{Appendix }}
}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries} 
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}

\makeglossaries  

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][\theglstoctitle]{%
  \def\theglstoctitle{#2}%
  \vspace{\cftbeforelottitleskip}%
  \par\noindent
  {\cftlottitlefont #2}{\cftafterlottitle}%
  \vskip\cftafterlottitleskip
% Uncomment the next line if you want an entry in the table of contents:
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}#1}%
}

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}
\newglossaryentry{Pi}{
name=$\pi$,
description={A mathematical constant whose value is the ratio of any circle's circumference to its diameter.},
sort=symbpi, type=symbolslist
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\printglossaries

\chapter{Sample}
This is my \gls{sa} and I can use it again. This is a symbol \gls{Pi}.
\begin{table}
 \caption{Sample Table}
\end{table}
\updatechaptername
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Edit:**

If you want to insert a page break after each glossary you can do:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{\clearpage}
```

Or if you want to increase the vertical space after each glossary you can do:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{\vspace*{1cm}}
```

(Change `1cm` to the appropriate length.)

Comment: Thanks Nicola. I will try but i am also using a style file. Actual printing of glossary happens in .sty file which i got from my university. So I will need to bring portion of the .sty file here. Probably that portion is linked to other places in .sty file so i will have to bring that too. However I will try my best because i know that is the best way to get your help. Is it possible that i could send the .sty file because that is the part which haunts me?
I thank all of you Nicola, cfr as well as cgnieder for taking interest in my post.

Comment: @Tash If the glossary printing stuff is dealt with by your university's custom package, I suggest you ask the author of that package about it. (Modify my example so that it uses the custom .sty so you've got a MWE when you contact the package author.) If the package is publicly available you could put a link to it from here.

Comment: Nicola, The first thing I did was to contact the author who was a student and have left. He responded but he seems busy. I modified part of his style file as he did not have glossary function working. Give me some time and I shall get back.

Comment: Hi. I was finally able to make a MWE but it is about 1000 characters too long for this forum :)

Comment: @Tash It sounds like you might be better off not using that package and use a class like `scrbook`, `scrreprt` or `memoir` that can be customised to fit your university requirements. I have a [tutorial on using LaTeX to write a thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/) if that's of any help.

Comment: @Tash a MWE should rarely need to be more than 50 lines or so, just delete everything from your current MWE that still allows the file to run and show the problem.

Comment: How to paste the code to be nicely formatted?

Comment: I tried to paste the code in two parts but there was no formatting. How could i achieve the formatting as done by you people very nicely in above example codes?

Comment: @Tash Select the code and click on the button that looks like `{}`

Comment: I just posted the MWE. Please note that I can comment the part of the code which makes the chapter heading smaller but i want to keep it. If I comment then all the headings are same which i don't want. I want to List of table/figure heading as well as Acronyms/Symbols heading bigger while chapter heading bit smaller (as they already appear here). In summary, I just want the list of acronyms/symbols to match that of list of tables/figure.